# Extract bitfields from an int in Python

Tags: python, bit, bit-fields

I have a number like `0x5423` where I want to extract 4 values:

```
a = 0x5   # 15 downto 12
b = 0x42  # 11 downto 3
c = 0x3   # 3 downto 2
d = 0x00  # 1 downto 0
```

I discovered the module [bitstrings](https://github.com/scott-griffiths/bitstring) that looks great. Unfortunately, for an unknown reason, the bits are numbered from the right.

This is bad because if a add some upper bits like `0xA5423` my extraction won't work anymore:

```
field = bitstrings.BitArray('0x5423')
a = field[0:4].uint
b = field[4:12].uint
c = field[12:14].uint
d = field[14:16].uint
```

How can I properly extract my bitfields without complex arithmetic manipulations such as:

```
b = (a >> 4) & 0xFF
```

Ideally I would have:

```
b = field.range(11, 4)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Convert the string to `0x####` format before pass to `bitstring.BitArray`:

```
>>> n = '0xA5423'
>>> n = '0x{:04x}'.format(int(n, 16) & 0xffff)  # => '0x5423'
>>> field = bitstring.BitArray(n)
>>> field[0:4].uint
5
>>> field[4:12].uint  # 0x42 == 66
66
>>> field[12:14].uint
0
>>> field[14:16].uint
3
```

**UPDATE** another solution that does not depend on `bitstring`, and count from left(according to OP):

Convert the number into binary format:

```
>>> n = '0xA5423'
>>> n = format(int(n, 16), '016b')[::-1]  # reversed
>>> n
'11000100001010100101'
>>> int(n[0:2][::-1], 2)  # need to reverse again to get proper value
3
>>> int(n[2:4][::-1], 2)
0
>>> int(n[4:12][::-1], 2)
66
>>> int(n[12:16][::-1], 2)
5
```