# Python how to mask and int with bitfields

Tags: python, bit-fields

Sorry if this is a beginner question - my experience with bitfields is zero.   I have a series of 25 flags represented by Bitfields and an session integer which represents any flags set at this time.   I want to mask the integer e.g. 268698112 and see what flags are set.

```py
class Flags:
    flaga = 0x0001
    flagi = 0x0100
    flagp = 0x8000
    flagq = 0x010000
    flagv = 0x10000000
```

I have tried the following two lines but they only return zero.

```py
test_a = session & flag_mask
test_b = (session >> flag_mask) & 1
```

I have looked at [Extract bitfields from an int in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34174198/extract-bitfields-from-an-int-in-python) and although I can see Bitstrings might be helpful I cannot see how to then add the integer into the mix without getting an error for example I have tried:

```py
bitstring.Bits(session) & bitstring.BitArray(flag_mask)
(bitstring.Bits(session) >> bitstring.BitArray(flag_mask)) & 1
```

but get

```py
Bitstrings must have the same length for and operator
< not supported between instances of "BitArray" and "int"
```

How can I extract true or false values from the session int for the given flags?

**SOLUTION**

So I actually have the solution above but with 25 possible flags I just didn't have the confidence to check all of them and realise so. The following function returns a list of set flags.

```py
def decode_flags(flagcode, flagObject):
    flags = [a for a in dir(flagObject) if not a.startswith('__')]
    enabled_flags = []
    for attr in flags:
        flag_mask = (getattr(flagObject, attr))
            if flagcode & flag_mask:
                enabled_flags.append(attr)
```

Comment: Only `268698112 & flagv` is non zero, the other flags are not present, but unknow flags are (convert them and session to binary and compare them). [IntFlag](https://docs.python.org/3/library/enum.html#enum.IntFlag) can be used to handle cases like this. Also writing as binary or exponents is less confusing: `0x8 == 0b1000 == 2**3`

Comment: bitwise and (a.k.a. `&`) is enough for anding between numbers (numbers ARE bitfields). If you're getting zeros it's because your flags aren't actually set. Just make sure you have defined your flags and "session" correctly

Comment: What is `flag_mask`? Is it one of your `flag?` variables? Also, `session >> flag_mask` doesn't make sense.

Comment: @quamrana   Yes flag_mask is one of the flags.   Good to know session >> flag_mask doesn't make sense -it doesn't work!  I found it on a page that was talking about bitfield masking.

Comment: Taking the example from @ivvija: You *could* have: `mask_num = 3; flagd = 2**mask_num; test_a = session & flagd; test_b = (session >> mask_num) & 1` and both `test_a` and `test_b` would be `True`.

Answer (score 2):

**Docs for [IntFlag](https://docs.python.org/3/library/enum.html#enum.IntFlag) and [Flag](https://docs.python.org/3/library/enum.html#enum.Flag)**

I know you have a solution, but still wanted to share how to use IntFlag for this.
I used your example value of `268698112` (`0b10000000001000000001000000000`).

**Create an IntFlag class with your flags:**

```py
from enum import IntFlag, KEEP

class SessionFlag(IntFlag, boundary=KEEP):
    flaga = 2**0  # rightmost bit
    flagi = 2**8  # 9th from right since zero based
    flagp = 2**15
    flagq = 2**16
    flagv = 2**28
```

To convert an `int` pass it to the constructor.
IntFlag does not discard undefined flags, but they are returned all as one int "remainder".

Remainder `262656` is `0b1000000001000000000`, so two undefined flags.

```
>>> session = SessionFlag(268698112)
>>> session
<SessionFlag.flagv|262656: 268698112>
```

**Get defined flags as list:**

```
>>> list(session)
[<SessionFlag.flagv: 268435456>]
```

**Check flags:**

```
>>> SessionFlag.flagq in session
False
>>> SessionFlag.flagv in session
True
>>> SessionFlag(2**9) in session  # convert undefined flag for checking
True
>>> SessionFlag(2**13) in session  # convert undefined flag for checking
False
```

Comment: Thank you @ivvija,  might be a useful answer for someone.